# Performance tuning C# permutations and SHA1 code

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm

Although this is a university assignment (homework) I've come to the best solution I could think of. I would achieve full marks with this code as it matches the question, however I was specially allowed to develop it in C# rather than everyone else using Java, kind of a "yeh, show what c# can do" challenge ;-)

The question was:

Create a program to find the password of a SHA1 hash using a brute force technique, assuming passwords are 6 characters long and can only contain lower-case a-z and 0-9.

I created a LINQ query and after I have the possible combinations I need to run them through SHA1 to get a hash and compare it to the provided password hash.

I created this code:

```
public static string BruteForceHash(string hash)
        {

                var results = from c0 in Enumerable.Range(0, 36)
                              from c1 in Enumerable.Range(0, 36)
                              from c2 in Enumerable.Range(0, 36)
                              from c3 in Enumerable.Range(0, 36)
                              from c4 in Enumerable.Range(0, 36)
                              from c5 in Enumerable.Range(0, 36)
                              select new string(
                                  new[]
                                {
                                    Characters[c0],
                                    Characters[c1],
                                    Characters[c2],
                                    Characters[c3],
                                    Characters[c4],
                                    Characters[c5],
                                }
                                  );

                string found = null;
                Parallel.ForEach(results, (result, loopstate, a) =>
                                              {
                                                  string hashed = SHA1(result, Encoding.Default);

                                                  if (hashed == hash)
                                                  {
                                                      found = result;
                                                      loopstate.Break();
                                                  }
                                              });

                if (found != null)
                {
                    return found;
                }

            return "Not found.";
        }
```

Now my real problem is that it solved easy passwords quickly ("aaaaaa" is instant) but obviously takes longer the further the password is away from "aaaaaa".

I would hope someone could provide some pointers on how to increase the performance.

Comment: Reduce overhead, that's just about it. You could handcraft a SHA1 implementation that used 6 characters. You could try to reduce GC overhead, like why are you using Enumerable.Range? Why not: `from c1 in Characters`? Also, you might look into trying: `select ("" + c0 + c1 +c 2) + ("" + c3 + c4 + c5)` instead of your array-based string constructors. However, this just goes to show, brute-force is slow.

Comment: Does "run it on a really big box with lots of cores" count? Heck, run it on an azure cluster...

Comment: Do you want to performance tune while still keeping it readable and idiomatic C#, or do you want performance at the expense of everything else? Obviously you could `unsafe` everything and use your own custom SHA1 implementation and thread management optimised for your exact scenario, but that would end up reading much more like C++ than the C# that we all know and love.

Comment: Run it through http://brahma.ananthonline.net/ and execute it on a GPU.

Comment: See https://lassevk.kilnhg.com/Repo/StackOverflow/answers/SO4944816 for my attempt at this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, my thought about using Azure did come up but I would demo it on my laptop (i7 (HT, 8cores), 6GB, SSD) although I would have internet access ;).

Comment: @Lasse Nice optimizations.  It might be worth demonstrating the difference between the fastest solution, and the "best" solution that maximizes readability.

Comment: @Lasse you should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: The optimisations are nice, wondering if the byte[] compare section would be quicker with Enumerable.SequenceEqual, perhaps more readable?

Comment: Yes Lasse post as the answer (I'll accept it!), I think your code has given me more performance and a few more ideas on how to improve my code. Although I'm adding long comments/msdn links to explain how it works so the Java people won't be really confused ;-)

Comment: While Enumerable.SequenceEqual might be more readable, from a raw performance perspective the for loop is better since it does not create short-lived objects that must be collected. Lasse's most recent updates move away from strings for (I would assume) just that sort of benefit.

Comment: Preprocess, build a B-tree on disk, and use that as a lookup table. ;)

Comment: @Peter I did suggest the use of Rainbow tables but alas the lecturer forbid it, has to be fully generated at runtime :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fairly happy with the implementation then I would run the code with a performance profiler like [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/dotnet/download/index.jsp) or [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) you can look at the hot spot in the code and look at tuning from there.  Sometimes its nice to do this when you are using syntacticly sugared code like LINQ, that way you can get a feel for whats really going on under the hood too...